# Check Checkbox from code behind asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox

I want to change my `Checkbox` states when I write any thing in a `textbox` so I did

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkIceChest" Text="Ice Chest" runat="server" />
<asp:TextBox ID="txtIceChest" Text="$ cost" runat="server" CssClass="moch-cost" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="CalculateStand" />
```

and

```
protected void CalculateStand(object s, EventArgs e)
{
     double total = 0, cost = 0;
     if (txtIceChest.Text.Length > 0 && txtIceChest.Text != "$ cost")
     {
         cost = Convert.ToDouble(txtIceChest.Text.Replace("$", ""));
         total += cost;
         if (cost > 0) chkIceChest.Checked = true;
     }
}
```

but it is not working !!!! why ?

Comment: it will work when your textbox lose focus...

Comment: I really think you should look at using client side script for this. Do you really want to post back to the server every time the textbox value changes just to update something in the UI? Madness my friend, madness.

Comment: @AmitSingh I know but it is not working

Comment: @RichAndrews yes I save some data and calculate others

Comment: I am with Rich Andrews, you should look into a client-side solution, I recommend KnockoutJS, the two-way data-binding between the DOM and your view model will allow what you are doing plus much more.  Posting back to the server on text events to update a checkbox is a path of disaster that will be a pit of failure when you start adding multiple things that need to "update" other UI controls.

Comment: @RichAndrews, I agreed with you in so much that I went ahead and provided the OP that solution. I've been maintaining some old projects here at work lately and somebody used an `UpdatePanel` to do something like this. :(

Answer (score 4):

How about a client-side approach? I mean, to be perfectly honest, UI operations like this are best fit there. First, you'll need to change your markup a little:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkIceChest"
              ClientIDMode="Static"
              Text="Ice
              Chest" runat="server" />
<asp:TextBox ID="txtIceChest"
             ClientIDMode="Static"
             Text="$ cost"
             runat="server"
             CssClass="moch-cost" />
```

and now you'll need a little JavaScript, just throw this on your `ASPX` page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#txtIceChest').blur(function() {
        var total = 0;
        var cost = 0;
        var val = $('#txtIceChest').val();
        var chkIceChest = $('#chkIceChest');

        if (val && val.length > 0 && val != "$ cost") {
            cost = val.replace('$', '');
            total += cost;
            if (cost > 0) {
                chkIceChest.attr('checked', 'checked');
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

but this approach would happen in the browser and real-time for you. Also, the value would get posted back just as if the user had checked the check box.

Comment: So this function will work on textchange or only when page is loading ?

Comment: @kartal, currently it works on `blur`. Like your current code did. However, if you want it on text changed then just use `change` instead of `blur`.

Comment: It is not working for me . did you miss anything because I am not good in javascript

Comment: @kartal: you need to [download](http://jquery.com/download/) and [link](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_src.asp) the jQuery JavaScript file for this code to work.

Comment: I already have it <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>

Comment: @kartal, put some `alert` dialogs in the code (e.g. `alert('Started method...');` and see how far it's getting. You can actually debug the JavaScript in IE9+, FireFox (with Firebug), and Chrome too. Cause it looks right to me -but clearly there must be an error somewhere.

Comment: yes I did that and I found the browser call the function only one time at loading

Comment: @kartal: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31683/discussion-between-michael-perrenoud-and-kartal)